# Handling HttpWebrequest post data at the end point

Tags: rest, httpwebrequest, payload

Hi I am trying to make a call to external rest service using httpwebrequest. I am sending some payload with the httpwebrequest. Now I am trying to code the endpoint. I am not able to figure out the how to get the payload that I sent along with httpwebrequest? I may sound stupid but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is same as making a rest call using any rest client. you can get the payload using "args" parameter.

for example I am sending a Json Object in the payload. Then I can receive it using the following code:

JObject items = args.payload["items"];

Not sure if it helps anybody.